# Selecting a cell on top of a range

Tags: excel, vba

I now have a range A2:A10
But I need to select A1, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Sorry I should be more specific. It's part of a loop so the range is dynamic.
The following code solved my problem. I needed this to work for any columns not just A2:A10.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim myRange As Range, desiredRange As Range
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10")
    Set desiredRange = myRange.Resize(1, 1).Offset(-1)
    desiredRange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: set the range then use offset()............... Range("A1").select will select A1 lol

Comment: A quick caveat to @ThisGuyJustNeedsHelp solution. If you use `.Offset(-1)` on `Range("A2:A10")`, it will select `Range("A1:A9")`. If you truly only want cell A1, then use `Range("A2:A10").Range("A1").Offset(-1)`. In this case, `.Range("A1")` indicates that you want to select the first cell in the range. For example, `Range("B2:B10").Range("A1").Offset(-1).Select` selects B1

Comment: Sorry I should be more specific. It's part of a loop so the range is dynamic. How would I select A2 from A2:A10?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear and explain what you have and what you want to do?

Comment: @GarryWang please share your code so people don't have to guess what your set up is. This will save volunteer time and help you get to a solution faster.

Comment: From your description you would just `Range("A1").Select`. Otherwise, clarify the question. In what way is the range changing dynamically and why are you selecting A1, or A2 (or A200)?

Comment: Chances are, you do not need to `.Select` anything. Again, all of this guess work is due to you not just sharing your code.

Comment: Your question is also inconsistent. First you say you need to select `A1` from `A2:A10` and then you say you need to select `A2` from `A2:A10`..... **Help us help you**

Comment: The question is a moving, fuzzy, target. Now the answer is just `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select`.

Comment: Share your code including loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no loop shown in your code. If you repeatedly set the variable `myRange` using a single column then you simply use

```
myRange.Cells(1,1)
```

to refer to the first cell

Answer (score 0):

set the range then loop item in range and select first item:

```
  Dim Cell As Range, ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = ActiveSheet

  For Each Cell In ws.Range("A2:A10")
      Cell.Select
      exit for
  Next Cell
```

Comment: How is this different from just `Range("A2").Select`?

Comment: user wants to select first cell in their range whether the cell be in A30 or A100, like his range could be A30:A50 and they want to select the first cell which is A30.

Comment: This needs to be resized and then offset. OPs question is inconsistent. He first states he needs the cell ABOVE the range, then says he needs the top cell IN the range.

Comment: @urdearboy Thank you! I looked up the resize function and i think that's the answer to my question.

Comment: @GarryWang what are you trying to do, please clarify your question because if you just want the first cell of your range, then my answer answers your question.